# Error python: Python in worker has different version 3.9 than that in driver 3.10

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark

I Installed Python 3.10 with command: brew install python@3.10 Then i installed pyspark with brew. I did which python3 I got this directory /usr/bin/python3 and .bash_profile and added this two rows

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.
```

I installed Jupyter brew install jupyter I did vi on /opt/homebrew/bin/jupyter and modified the default value written that was python3.11 by 3.10 #!/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.10/bin/python3.10 I thought I finished all the installations, then I executed Jupyter notebook and run the code below

```
 data = [("Java", "20000"), ("Python", "100000"), ("Scala", "3000")]
 df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
 df.show()
```

When running the code above, I got the error below.

RuntimeError: Python in worker has different version 3.9 than that in driver 3.10, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions. Please check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set.
I spent more then 3 days on this problem and was not able to solve it. I hope to be clear explaining my problem, who can help me please?

no error at the end